# How to alter search query to include custom fields?

Tags: users, search, database

How can I alter the query for user search (using normal Drupal search) so that instead of searching only email and username, it will also search custom user fields (from fields module)?

Comment: Which search? normal Drupal search/SOLR/Search API

Comment: Normal Druapl search

Answer (score 1):

For the normal Drupal search you can do so by defining a **custom search type** in a module.

Use [hook_search_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.api.php/function/hook_search_info/7) to define your custom search type & [hook_search_execute($keys = NULL, $conditions = NULL)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.api.php/function/hook_search_execute/7) to create or extend your search query.

More available hooks can be found at the Drupal's Search interface or by looking up the **search** contrib module under **yourdrupal\modules\search\search.api.php**

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is install the [Search api module](https://drupal.org/project/search_api)

And upon enabling the module, go to **admin/config/search/search_api**, and click add index. Add an index of item type user. Once that is done all custom user fields will be listed with a checkbox in front of them. Select the fields you want indexed and this would then make custom user fields searchable.